# iOS App review - Can I place demo features?

Tags: ios, review

I have a demo feature which is not implemented in the app yet. Can this cause a rejection during the review process?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about App Store policy that is non-technical and subject to change.

Comment: @Justin - is there a better place to post this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Apple App store guidelines 2.9 you cannot include demo features in you app

> 2.9 Apps that are "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected. Beta Apps may only be submitted through TestFlight and must follow the TestFlight guidelines

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: including the words 'demo' or 'beta' in the app can be cause for rejection, even if the features are flawless.  We were once rejected for using the word beta on our website (not in the app)